# C++ newbie: using stream for writing data to file... Why does my code introduce a carriage return?

Tags: c++, string, stream, streaming

I have written code for performing calculations.  There is a loop in the code.  Each loop corresponds to a different time.

For each loop, I want to write a string to an external file.  The string should contain "filename_" and the number of the loop--for example:

'fileName_4'

The problem is that it is appearing as (with the closing ' on the line below):

'fileName_4
'

If anyone could help, I would be very grateful.  Here is what I have tried:

```
std::string       convertedToString;
std::stringstream numberConverted; 

storeNumberForConversion << time << endl;   // time is a number, like the 4 in the example above
convertedToString = numberConverted.str() += "'";


fileNameHighestTimeStream.open ("fileName.txt", ios::out | ios::app );
fileNameHighestTimeStream << "'fileName_" << convertedToString << endl; 
fileNameHighestTimeStream.close();
```

I have also tried:

```
storeNumberForConversion << time << endl;   // time is a number, like the 4 in the example above
convertedToString = numberConverted.str();


fileNameHighestTimeStream.open ("fileName.txt", ios::out | ios::app );
fileNameHighestTimeStream << "'fileName_" << convertedToString << "'" << endl; 
fileNameHighestTimeStream.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::string       convertedToString;
std::stringstream numberConverted; 

storeNumberForConversion << time << endl;   // time is a number, like the 4 in the example above
convertedToString = numberConverted.str() += "'";
```

Presumably this is a typo, and you have:

```
std::string       convertedToString;
std::stringstream numberConverted; 

numberConverted << time << endl;   // time is a number, like the 4 in the example above
convertedToString = numberConverted.str() += "'";
```

You streamed `endl` to `numberConverted`, so it contains a newline. Simple!

From your comment elsewhere:

> I thought the endl would flush the stream? If I DON'T include the endl, should I worry about flushing the stream? If so, how would I do it without endl?

`<< endl` is the same as `<< '\n' << flush`. So you can still do the flushing yourself with `<< flush`, but actually usually you should just leave this up to the stream object to handle in its own time.

Also the use of `+=` is suspect (though it happens to yield the correct result in this case).

Fixed:

```
std::stringstream numberConverted;
numberConverted << time;

std::string       convertedToString;
convertedToString = numberConverted.str() + "'";
```

Answer (score 3):

The endl adds the new line. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot Leon and red1ynx...  I thought the endl would flush the stream?  If I DON'T include the endl, should I worry about flushing the stream?  If so, how would I do it without endl?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Ant: `<< endl` is the same as `<< '\n' << flush`. So you can still flush, but frankly I really wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tomalak.  Sorry for the silly question!  I don't know where I would be without you guys at stackoverflow!

Comment: endl is more portable than '\n' as in Unix it is '\n\r' (from memory)

Answer (score 3):

`storeNumberForConversion << time << endl;`

You should remove `endl` at the end.

`storeNumberForConversion << time;`